# Column in table not getting updated but not showing error

Tags: php, laravel

Hello everyone I'm getting confused because when I'm running a code with some condition only 1 column getting updated and the others column stay null, I'm sure there is no typo with the column name in table nor in code here is my code :

```
public function solusi_line($id)
{
    $idasli  = base64_decode($id);
    $solusi = solusi::where('request_id', $idasli)->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
    $count = solusi::where('request_id', $idasli)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->count();
    $cekakun = Session::get('id');
    $adminkah = Admin::where('user_id', $cekakun)->count();
    // dd($solusi);
    //jika admin ke bagian sini
    if ($adminkah != 0) {
        # code...
        return view('admin.detail_feedback', compact('solusi', 'count'));
    } else {
        return view('user.detailfeedback_user', compact('solusi', 'count'));
    }

    //klo user kebagian user

}
public function FirstFeedback($id)
{
    $datas = Kirim::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('admin.detailprogress', compact('datas'));
}
//solusi dari admin
public function solusiPost(Request $request)
{
    $itungsolusi = solusi::where('request_id', $request->idRequest)->count();
    $data = new solusi();
    $data->request_id = $request->idRequest;
    $data->pengirim_id = Session::get('id');
    $data->penerima_id = $request->idPenerima;
    $data->solusi = $request->solusi;
    $file = $request->file('lampiran_solusi');
    if (!empty($file)) {
        $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $name = time() . '.' . $ext;
        $file->move('upload/lampiran/', $name);
        $data->lampiran = $name;
        $data->url_lampiran = url('upload/lampiran') . "/" . $name;
    } else {
        $data->lampiran = null;
        $data->url_lampiran = null;
    }
    if ($data->save()) {
        //matiin sementara
        $check = DB::table('kirims')->where('id', $data->request_id)->first();
        $user = Kirim::find($check->id);
        // dd($user);
        if (!is_null($user)) {
            // $user->update(['status' => 'CheckByUser', 'status_feedback' => 'Ya']);
            $user->update(['remarks' => 'Ya', 'status' => 'CheckByUser', 'status_feedback' => 'Ya']);
        }
        //just status column is success to update but not the remarks and status_feedback column
        $id_solusi = $data->id;
        $thisUser = DB::table('kirims')
            ->join('simpan_users', 'kirims.pengirim_id', '=', 'simpan_users.user_id')
            ->join('solusis', 'kirims.id', '=', 'solusis.request_id')
            ->where('kirims.id', $data->request_id)
            ->where('solusis.id', $id_solusi)
            ->select('kirims.email', 'kirims.ticket_id', 'solusis.solusi', 'solusis.lampiran', 'solusis.url_lampiran')
            ->first();
        // dd($thisUser);
```

here the problem

```
$check = DB::table('kirims')->where('id', $data->request_id)->first();
        $user = Kirim::find($check->id);
        // dd($user);
        if (!is_null($user)) {
            // $user->update(['status' => 'CheckByUser', 'status_feedback' => 'Ya']);
            $user->update(['remarks' => 'Ya', 'status' => 'CheckByUser', 'status_feedback' => 'Ya']);
        }
        //just status column is success to update but not the remarks and status_feedback column
```

I really appreciate for any help, I getting stuck because laravel not showing error too, thank you.

Comment: can you share your `Kirim` model code?? probably the problem is in mass assignment.

Comment: is it fillable in model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your `Kirim` model, where you need to define `$fillable` property. Something like below.

```
 class Kirim extends Model {  

     protected $fillable = ['remarks', 'status', 'status_feedback',''];   

     // All fields inside $fillable array can be mass-assigned  

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

use update statement like this.

```
 $user->remarks = 'Ya',
$user->status = 'CheckByUser',
$user->status_feedback = 'Ya'
$user->update();
```

few days ago i faced the same issue and fixed it as i told you .